# In Golang, uint16 VS int, which is less cost?

Tags: go

I am using a 64Bit server. My golang program needs integer type.

SO, If I use uint16 and uint32 type in source code, does it cost more than use most regular int type?

I am considering both computing cost and developing cost.

Comment: What do you mean "cost"? Unless you're storing billions of these and doing billions of operations on them I doubt you'd even notice the difference. Use whatever representation covers the values you're likely to encounter.

Comment: The cost also including developer writing lines to convert variable type in source-code.

Comment: If you're converting all the time you've picked the wrong type.

Comment: You could look at [golang-sizeof](http://golang-sizeof.tips/?source=djinn) for this category of calculations.

Comment: @djinn This online tool is so useful! It solved my question. I thought bool and int16 will still waste 64 bits memory.

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the vast majority of cases using `int` makes more sense.
Here are some reasons:

1. Go doesn't implicitly convert between the numeric types, even when you think it should. If you start using some unsigned type instead of `int`, you should expect to pepper your code with multiple type conversions, because of other libraries or APIs preferring not to bother with unsigned types, because of untyped constant numerical expressions returning `int` values, etc.
2. Unsigned types are more prone to underflowing than signed types, because 0 (an unsigned type's boundary value) is much more of a naturally occurring value in computer programs than, for example, -9223372036854775808.
3. If you want to use an unsigned type because it restricts the values that you can put in it, keep in mind that when you combine silent underflow and compile time-only constant propagation, you probably aren't getting the bargain you were looking for. For example, while you cannot convert the constant `math.MinInt64` to a `uint`, you can easily convert an `int` variable with value `math.MinInt64` to a `uint`. And arguably it's not a bad Go style to have an `if` check whether the value you're trying to assign is valid for your program.

Unless you are experiencing significant memory pressure and your value space is somewhere slightly over what a smaller signed type would offer you, I'd think that using `int` will be much more efficient even if only because of development cost.
And even then, chances are that either there's a problem somewhere else in your program's memory footprint, or a managed language like Go is not the best fit for your needs.